# Is it possible to run the test phase seperatly by maven?

Tags: maven, jenkins-pipeline

Is it possible to seperate the maven test phase? Basically i want to create a pipeline step where the whole application gets build and installed without tests.

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

Something like that should do the first part. Is it possible to start a 2nd pipeline step that only executes the tests? As far as i understand the maven phase test, includes also compile and validate. Can they be excluded somehow?

Comment: You may use `mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true` to compile and `mvn test` to test.

Comment: Isn´t it possible to make the process leaner with `mvn compile` and/or `maven test-compile`?

Comment: If you specify `compile`, that's a lifecycle phase. But you could use `compiler:compile` and `compiler:testCompile`, to run _just_ the compiler, at the risk of skipping over a lot of important stuff. For most purposes skipping tests initially would be an adequate time win.

Comment: Can you elaborate what gets skipped? Do i need to use compile and testCompile or does one include the other?

Comment: Why want you to separate things like that? And why not running `mvn clean test` or `mvn clean verify` ?

Comment: Why would i do that? test and verify are included in the install process. I need the separate install and test phases because the project structure is a mess (circular dependencies on test level) and this way i can use two build steps in a pipeline job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved with a pipeline job that first executes maven `dependency:resolve clean install -DskipTests` at all modules and later in parallel steps `maven surefire:test`.